# httr::oauth1.0_token returns HTTP 403

Tags: r, twitter-oauth, httr

I tried to use `httr::oauth1.0_token` to authenticate against Twitter, but I got an error:

```r
library(httr)
oauth1.0_token(oauth_endpoints("twitter"), 
               oauth_app("tw", key = Sys.getenv("Twitter_API"), 
                         secret = Sys.getenv("Twitter_Key")))

# Error in init_oauth1.0(self$endpoint, self$app, permission = self$params$permission,  : 
#   Forbidden (HTTP 403).
```

As I am new to `OAuth` authentication, I started reading the [Twitter Docs](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/authentication/oauth-1-0a/obtaining-user-access-tokens) and [built the authentication dance from scratch](https://gist.github.com/thothal/7394d226d3506c3a501dc28a1930f856).

After a lot of trial and error, I was eventually successful, so I can rule out that something on the twitter app setting end is wrong (that is the endpoint is set up correctly and especially the callback URL is defined properly, furthermore `key` and `secret` are the correct ones).

Before filing a bug report, I wanted to double check that I am using `oauth1.0_token` correctly. Thus, is this a bug or am I the bug?